# Every User Access Denied in Whole web application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, user-accounts

I access whole web application but while, I **check Permission** in every List message "Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you."

I have Web application Primary admin/Full access rights

**Tried Solution** : I've already added myself through Application Mangement > Manage Applications > User Policy

Also, logged int the site as sharepointadmin and shared with myself

Answer (score 0):

I would check to verify the following...

1. You are a site collection administrator
2. Your account has access to SQL as a DBO
3. You are not in a user policy on the web application where you explicitly added the "Deny" permission level.
4. Login with a a Service Account on the server and see if you can access it.

Also always make sure you are using IE and not Chrome for these types of troubleshooting.

It is possible for Farm level administrators to be locked out of a Site Collection if they are not given access.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm a site collection admin,SQL DBO,I tried with service account,but I can't understand point no 3,I tried with IE also..@rich